# if , else if - javascript function works only one time

Tags: javascript, css

My javascript works only one time. There are already questions like this, but sill I'm not able to fix this simple thing.

I want to change `visibility: hidden; -> visibility: visible;` and vice versa.

```js
let toggleNavStatus = false;

function toggleNav() {
  let getSidebar = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar");

  if (toggleNavStatus === false) {
    getSidebar.style.visibility = "visible";
    let toggleNavStatus = true;
  } else if (toggleNavStatus === true) {
    getSidebar.style.visibility = "hidden";
    let toggleNavStatus = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.nav-sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<a href=# onclick="toggleNav()">button</a>

<aside class="nav-sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  </ul>
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6x84mdvu/1/)
(actually it is not working in fiddle?)

Comment: You re-declare your `toggleNavStatus` in every `if`. Remove `let`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you are redeclaring your `toggleNavStatus` within your `if` statement. When you use `let` in your if-statement, you are referring to a new variable `toggleNavStatus` within your `if` statement (ie a local variable), not the one you declared at the beginning of your function, thus it doesn't change.

See working example below:

```js
let toggleNavStatus = false;

function toggleNav() {
  let getSidebar = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar");

  if (toggleNavStatus === false) {
    getSidebar.style.visibility = "visible";
    toggleNavStatus = true;
  } else if (toggleNavStatus === true) {
    getSidebar.style.visibility = "hidden";
    toggleNavStatus = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.nav-sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<a href=# onclick="toggleNav()">button</a>

<aside class="nav-sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> let toggleNavStatus = true;
> ```

You're creating a new *local* variable with the same name and setting that.

You never change the value of your global variable, so when you test `if (toggleNavStatus === false)` a second time, it is *still* `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You not changing the `toggleNavStatus` declared in global scope instead you a creating a new variable inside your if blocks. Don't use let again inside your if blocks

```js
let toggleNavStatus = false;

function toggleNav() {
let getSidebar = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar");

  if (toggleNavStatus === false) {
    getSidebar.style.visibility = "visible";
    toggleNavStatus = true;
  }
   else if (toggleNavStatus === true){
    getSidebar.style.visibility = "hidden";
    toggleNavStatus = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.nav-sidebar{
  width: 250px;
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<a href=# onclick="toggleNav()">button</a>

<aside class="nav-sidebar">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

corrected code:

```js
let toggleNavStatus = false;

function toggleNav() {
let getSidebar = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar");

  if (toggleNavStatus === false) {
    getSidebar.style.visibility = "visible";
    toggleNavStatus = true;
  }
   else if (toggleNavStatus === true){
    getSidebar.style.visibility = "hidden";
    toggleNavStatus = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.nav-sidebar{
  width: 250px;
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<a href=# onclick="toggleNav()">button</a>

<aside class="nav-sidebar">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create class **visible**  and than with javascript you should check if the class exist , so basically toggle class

[howto_js_toggle_class.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp)

Answer (score 0):

remove the let in if condition.Beacuse you are each time declare as new varible

```js
let toggleNavStatus = false;

function toggleNav() {
let getSidebar = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar");

  if (toggleNavStatus === false) {
    getSidebar.style.visibility = "visible";
     toggleNavStatus = true;
  }
   else if (toggleNavStatus === true){
    getSidebar.style.visibility = "hidden";
     toggleNavStatus = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.nav-sidebar{
  width: 250px;
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<a href=# onclick="toggleNav()">button</a>

<aside class="nav-sidebar">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're redeclaring `toggleNavStatus` in your condition statement which doesn't update the global `toggleNavStatus`.

Simply remove `let` in your if/else conditions.

```js
let toggleNavStatus = false;

function toggleNav() {
let getSidebar = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar");

  if (toggleNavStatus === false) {
    getSidebar.style.visibility = "visible";
    toggleNavStatus = true;
  }
   else if (toggleNavStatus === true){
    getSidebar.style.visibility = "hidden";
    toggleNavStatus = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.nav-sidebar{
  width: 250px;
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<a href=# onclick="toggleNav()">button</a>

<aside class="nav-sidebar">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
   </ul>
```